# Parsing through Bash

Tags: bash, csv

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a delimited text file using bash when the data looks like the following:

variable1: dataA,
variable2: dataA1,
variable3: dataA2

variable1: dataB,
variable2: dataB1,
variable3: dataB2

variable1: dataC,
variable2: dataC1,
variable3: dataC2

My goal is to make the data look like the following:

variable1, variable2, variable3

dataA, dataA1, dataA2

dataB, dataB1, dataB2,

dataC, dataC1, dataC2

Can anything help me with this?

Comment: Please use `code blocks` for readability

Comment: As @ghilesZ indicates, please [edit] the post so it reads better. Also, could you show what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#! /bin/bash
set -eu

header=1
first=1
values=""
while read -r key value ; do
    if [[ ! $key ]] ; then
        if [[ $header ]] ; then
            printf '\n%s' "$values"
        fi
        header=""
        first=1
        printf '\n'
        continue
    fi
    if [[ $header ]] ; then
        if [[ ! $first ]] ; then
            printf ,
        fi
        key=${key%:}
        printf '%s' "$key"
        values+=$value
    else
        printf '%s' "$value"
    fi
    first=""
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) input formats. Starting from

```
variable1: dataA
variable2: dataA1
variable3: dataA2

variable1: dataB
variable2: dataB1
variable3: dataB2

variable1: dataC
variable2: dataC1
variable3: dataC2
```

and simply running

```
mlr --x2c --ips ": " cat ./input.txt >./output.tx
```

you will have

```
variable1,variable2,variable3
dataA,dataA1,dataA2
dataB,dataB1,dataB2
dataC,dataC1,dataC2
```

Some notes:

- `--x2c` to convert from [XTAB](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file-formats.html#xtab-vertical-tabular) to CSV
- `--ips ": "` to set the pair separator